# How to solve org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException in Spring MVC when I sunmit a json string that is larger than 1M?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I use Spring MVC @RequestParam to accept a form.
I am sumbit a form that contains a json string, and when the json string is larger than 1M , It is

```
{
    "timestamp":1556663224346,
    "status":400,
    "error":"Bad Request",
    "exception":"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException",
    "message":"Required String parameter 'corpId' is not present",
    "path":"/api/test"
}
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { "application/json;charset=UTF-8" })
    @ResponseBody
    public String test(
            @ApiParam(required = true, value = "json string") @RequestParam(required = true) String content)
```

I think it is because of the HttpMessageConvert can not convert it or it is has a limit for Json Serializing.

Comment: I try to debug ，when json string of form is larger than 1M , log : Did not find handler method for [/api/test]

Comment: what does it mean 'larger'? String length is more than 1_000_000 characters?

Comment: I store it in to a file , it larger than 1Mb ，I think it is tomcat in SpringBoot limit the http post body

Comment: "message":"Required String parameter 'corpId' is not present" but where is 'corpId' field in your API definition? It seems you have some other controller method which is called. Can you post your controller code.

Answer (score 0):

You exceed the default http-header-size(8kb), you could configure your server.max-http-header-size with a suitable number

Comment: the form data is in the http body, I used server.tomcat.max_http_post_size=-1
server.tomcat.max_swallow_size=-1, but it doesn't effect.